# Как исправить график? И отобразить значения, и главное корректировать в коде по которым строится график?

Tags: matplotlib

Помогите ,пожалуйста, необходимо построить график зависимости баллистического падения тела в Python.Есть дифференциальные уравнения зависимостей угла(o), скорости(V)(падает с начальной скоростью отличной от свободного падения), дальности(L) и высоты(H)(см. изображение 1).Есть модуль sympy, но он только находит производную.B=0.006,p=1.225,g=9.81,k=3.2,R=6371000 Подскажите, пожалуйста какой алгоритм кода должен быть, чтобы можно было ввести значения (o V L H), на экране отображались с течением времени(шаг 0,5с) изменяемые перечисленные значения для построения графика(H(L)). Спасибо.

мой код:

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
B=0.006
ro=1.225
g=9.81
k=3.2
R=6371000
v0=7000
h_0=9000
l_0=0
teta_0=0.349
dt = 0.0005
t_end=60
t=[0.0]
v=[v0]
h=[h_0]
l=[l_0]
teta=[teta_0]
while t[-1]<t_end:
    v.append(v[-1]+dt*(-B*v[-1]*v[-1]*ro/2-g*math.sin(teta[-1])))
    teta.append(teta[-1]+dt*(0.5*B*k*v[-1]*ro-g*math.sin(teta[-1]/v[-1]*(1-v[-1]*v[-1]/g/R))))
    h.append(h[-1]+dt*v[-1]*math.sin(teta[-1]))
    l.append(l[-1]+dt*v[-1]*math.cos(teta[-1]))
    t.append(t[-1]+dt)
 
plt.plot(l, h, '.-')
plt.show()
```

график получается не адекватный зависимости высоты от дальности (см рис 2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: дифференциальные уравнения это и есть первый рисунок)

Comment: `math.sin(teta[-1]/v[-1]...` - скобка не закрыта.

Comment: Обнулим ***B*** - уберём атмосферу. тета - угол траектории относительно горизонта. Если тело летит горизонтально, то по второй формуле производная тета равна нулю. Так не бывает. В пустом пространстве, как только тело вышло в горизонтальный полёт оно начинает снижаться, значит тета должен уйти в отрицательные числа. А у вас - ноль. Добавьте в вопрос уравнение движение и как вы его дифференцировали.

Comment: Если злополучный синус заменить на косинус, то для свободного падения получаются более адекватные графики.

Comment: Да, второе слагаемое во второй производной крепко наврано.